# If G has 7 vertices and 14 edges then either G has a subgraph with 5 vertices and 8 edges, or G is 4-regular

Tags: graph-theory

I'm working on a graph theory past paper question:

If a graph G has 7 vertices and 14 edges then either G has a subgraph with 5 vertices and 8 edges, or G is 4-regular.

I have been trying the following strategy: 
If G has a subgraph with 5 vertices and 8 edges, then we are done. So suppose it doesn't. I now want to show it must be 4-regular in this case.

I've managed to show that if G doesn't have a subgraph with 5 vertices and 8 edges then it can't have a vertex of degree 1 or 6. I've also shown that the minimum degree of the graph is less than or equal to 4, and the maximum degree is greater than or equal to 4.

I've also tried the opposite strategy: showing if G is not 4-regular then it must have said subgraph. Also stuck on this and not sure which strategy is simpler.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: If there is at least 1 node of degree d < 4, remove that node. In the rest of the graph, there is at least 1 node of degree <= 2*(14-d)/6 < 4. Remove that other node, this is a subgraph of 5 nodes and >= 8 edges. So now the min-degree is at least 4. Does it help?

Comment: Yes, it does! Thank you for your help :)